# Getting random server refuse from kubectl (xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:6443)

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, kubernetes-pod

I'm total beginner for kubernetes and tried various methods in stackoverflow, youtube and blogs. None of them worked for me.

When running kubectl command randomly getting following error:

Eg: kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server 192.168.1.105:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Name         : kubelet
Version      : 1.25.3
OS           : Rocky Linux with vmware player
Working nodes: Rocky Linux 2x with same software versions and specs

tried

```
swapoff -a
```

- Restarting services (docker, kubectl)
- Completely re-installed cluster
- Config file added : ~/home/.kube/config
- daemon.json added

Comment: Have you checked the kubeconfig file? Does it match the mentioned IP?

Comment: @KamolHasan yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below command will help to identify isssue

```
crictl info
```

Install CRI
The reason is we should tell which CRI should use for the cluster.
Every node should have same CRI. I prefer docker engine.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/

https://github.com/Mirantis/cri-dockerd

```
kubeadm init --cri-socket=unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock

kubeadm join 192.168.1.200:6443 --token 49tl1j.0txot1q9s94o6wu7  --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:98a02f3a60fc4c00f399726a5d2b61213a714f8c9be3700eb648315094fa9ee0 --cri-socket=unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
```